# For what do we need storage allocation?

Tags: c, memory-management, storage, memory-address

for what do we actually require manual storage allocation?

The only possible tasks which I could think about would be for bigger binary data which does not fit to a 32bit integer.

Is this correct?
What are other use cases?

Comment: when at compilation time we don't know the size required that time we use dynamic allocation

Comment: What does manual storage allocation mean? `malloc`, as opposed to automatic and static storage?

Comment: Here is good reason to use dynamic memory:  [**Advantages of Dynamic Memory Allocation**](http://www.technoplaza.net/programming/lesson6.php) and [**Lesson 6: Dynamic Memory Allocation**](http://www.technoplaza.net/programming/lesson6.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you need to do manual storage allocation every time that the size of your data is not known at compile time. Almost all situations fall into two categories:

- Your program must read data from files/networks/user inputs etc., and the exact amount of that data is not known at compile time, or
- Your program must produce and store some output, and the exact amount of that output is not known to you at the time when you write your program.

Many very common data structures assume an ability to allocate memory of arbitrary size, when the precise size is determined at runtime. Doing so lets the data structure "grow" and "shrink" dynamically, as the storage demands of your program change with the time and the amounts of data that it processes.

Comment: Dynamic allocation of memory allows you to not only allocate it during runtime, but also free it at will, thus enabling you to keep memory usage low if you don't need it. It also frees you from having to use static data just so that you can pass it further up the stack, as automatic variables are destroyed upon function return.

Answer (score 0):

tons of examples. Allocating memory to fill a struct, for example, a linked list struct.